# FBRequestConnection no respond

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm making a "FBRequestConnection" to get all the friends that play the game...

When I update the SDK of Facebook to the last one, this stop working. Because It was working before.

I have no respond, no success, no error. Any ideas?

```
NSString *query = @"SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1";
        // Set up the query parameter
        NSDictionary *queryParam = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:query, @"q", nil];
        // Make the API request that uses FQL
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                     parameters:queryParam
                                     HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error) {
                                  if (error) {
                                      [self debug:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]]];
                                  } else {
                                      [self debug:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Result: %@", [result objectForKey:@"data"]]];
                                  }
                              }];





 -(void)fbLogin {
    if (!_session.isOpen) {
        // create a fresh session object
        _session = [[FBSession alloc] init];

        // if we don't have a cached token, a call to open here would cause UX for login to
        // occur; we don't want that to happen unless the user clicks the login button, and so
        // we check here to make sure we have a token before calling open
        if (_session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
            // even though we had a cached token, we need to login to make the session usable
            [_session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState status,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                // we recurse here, in order to update buttons and labels
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"fbConnected" object:nil];
            }];
        }

        [self populateUserDetails];
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you test this in the API explorer to make sure something in your FQL query has not been deprecated?

Comment: @AdamG Yes I just did, It returns allot of uid, just like I expected.

Comment: Is your session state open?

Comment: @AdamG Yes actually i'm getting another info from the user, like uid, email, etc.. but I can't get this fql. And the weird part it's that I have no response, no error, no result

Comment: Btw, the permissions the user gave me: Permissions: (
    "user_friends",
    installed,
    "basic_info",
    "user_birthday",
    email,
    "user_location"
)

Comment: Have you tried testing FBSession.activeSession.isOpen and FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded just to make sure?

Comment: @AdamG I think is not created. NSLog(@"state %u %u", appDelegate.session.state, FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded); give me: state 513 1. How can i create it? isOpen = true

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38702/discussion-between-adamg-and-ernesto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the session with:

```
 [FBSession.activeSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession * session, FBSessionState state, NSError * error){
        if (!error){

        }
    }];
```

Comment: Hi adam, but Actually I'm using this. I modify my main post